# Setting a TextView to the value of an integer

Tags: java, android

```
public class DataHelper extends Activity{

    TextView tvRslt;

    public static int insert(String firstFB, String firstRL) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Integer a = new Integer(firstFB).intValue();
        Integer b = new Integer(firstRL).intValue();
        int firstResult = a / b;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);
```

I wanted to set the integer "firstResult" to display on the TextEdit "tvRslt".

How do I do this?

If any further information is required, let me know.

Comment: ok there's way too much missing here to be able to offer any decent answer. First thing, the variable firstResult is declared in the last line of the insert method and is not a class variable so how are you planning to set anything to it's value? Also what is the source code for the TextView object and Bundle object? also the firstResult declaration should be wrapped in a try / catch block to catch divide by zero exceptions.

Comment: Okay then, how do I set it to a class variable and how would I set the exception do catch anything divided by zero?

Comment: I've already tried "tvRslt.setText(firstResult)", integer values don't work so I set it to tvRslt.setText(String.valueOf(firstResult)), which should work, but I need to work out how I declare firstResult as a class variable...

Comment: Why do you want it to make it a instance variable?

Comment: Oh, I don't... I guess I'll change it to a class variable...  I'll get back to you.

Comment: Right, if I put tvRslt.setText(String.valueOf(firstResult)); under the onCreate method (which I have changed from protected to public which I'm guessing is changing from instance to class variable (I'm a novice)) and it's giving me an error saying "firstResult cannot be resolved to a variable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With exception handling:

```
try {
    tvRslt.setText(firstResult + "");
} catch (DivideByZeroException e) {
    // Do something with exception condition.
}
```

Without exception handling:

```
// Before dividing check if denominator is 0.
int firstResult = (b == 0) ? 0 : a / b;
tvRslt.setText(firstResult + "");
```

This does of course require that you have a reference to the textview, as I assume you have in the code you did not show us.